How to connect to AWS RDS Postgres via Node.js running on local machine
I have a Node.js app running on an ES2 instance which I can connect successfully to an AWS RDS Postgres database and run a SQL statement to return the results. Now I want to run that same app but on my local machine instead of the EC2 instance. Can it be done?
I tried using the same key pair instance as I am using for the EC2 instance and created an SSH tunnel with this command
(true endpoints replaced with XXX for security):
ssh -i ec2-db-keypair.pem -N -L localhost:8080:database-test-1.XXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 ec2-user@ec2-XXX.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

My Node server is listening on 8081 and when the user lands on the route /db I want it to connect to the database and run some SQL statements.
The connection pool below works from within the EC2 instance, but not from my local machine:
server.listen({ port: 8081 }, (err, address) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log(`Server listening at ${address}`);
});

server.get("/db", async (request, reply) => {
  console.log("connect to db using slonik");

  const pem = fs
    .readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../../eu-west-2-bundle.pem"))
    .toString();

  const pool = createPool(
// ec2 instance instead of localhost:8080 I use: database-test-1.XXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
    `postgresql://postges:mydbpassword@$localhost:8080/postgres`,
    {
      ssl: {
        ca: pem,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
      },
    }
  );

  pool.connect(async (connection) => {
    try {
      const resultNodejsMyTableRows = await connection.query(
        sql`SELECT * FROM nodejs_mytable ORDER BY id ASC`
      );
      console.log("nodejs_mytable=", { resultNodejsMyTableRows });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  return "look at console for responses\n";
});

Currently I get:
Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:database-test-1.XXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

Is this the correct way that the SSH tunnel works and if not can someone advise on the correct way?

what happens if in the connection string  you specify "database-test-1.XXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" instead of localhost, but at the same time you tell your laptop (using its host file) to resolve database-test-1.XXX.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com to 127.0.0.1?

@andresm53 - that seems to have got past the connection issue. Just can't find the table that I created earlier. Will investigate further. Thankyou
